# How to define a union(ish) operation on tuples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let us say we have 2 tuples whose elements are all distinct (relative to the given tuple they are apart of) and have some ordering relation already defined on them, given as:

$$t_1 =(\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3,\ldots,\psi_n)$$
and
$t_2 = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,\ldots,\alpha_m)$

and we wish (for whatever reason) to have a binary operation $*$ such that $t_1 * t_2$ yields a tuple $t_3$ which is such that:

1) There is no element from either $t_1$ or $t_2$ which is not in $t_3$

2) $t_3$ does not contain duplicate elements, so that each element of $t_3$ is distinct

3) The order of the elements in $t_3$ is that of the defined ordering relation that needs to be given.

So, for example:
Let $t_1 = (3,7,8,1)$
and $t_2 = (7,4,2,5,9)$

And let the relation of the elements that the operation of $*$ will go by, be the standard less-than relation.

So then we would have:
$t_1 * t_2 = t_3 = (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9)$

(note the lack of '$7$' appearing twice, as well as the fact that the elements are ordered according to $<$)

How would one be able to define this operation with just symbols or would defining $*$ via the rules given above be acceptable?

Thanks

edit: to get more exposure I'm adding a set-theory tag, since tuples are after all defined as (ordered) sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [discussion occurred between us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44221/discussion-between-boolean-functions-and-jmoravitz), so here I will highlight the end results.

Depending on how exactly you define a tuple, there are a number of options, but the end result is that the operation is essentially the set of all elements appearing in at least one of $t_1$ or $t_2$ placed into a tuple with entries in the same order as they would appear in the underlying set.

Interpreting tuples as ordered sets:

Letting $t_1 = (A,\prec_a)$ and $t_2 = (B,\prec_b)$ and the underlying set be $(X,\prec_x)$ of which both $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, we have:

$$t_1*t_2 = \left((A\cup B), \prec_x\cap (A\cup B)^2\right)$$

keeping in mind that an order on $X$ is itself a set and is a subset of the cartesian product of $X$ with itself.  The intersection them makes sense.  Alternatively, one could just refer to the resulting order for $t_1*t_2$ as the inherited order, for which various notations exist such as $\prec_x|_{A\cup B}$.

---

Interpreting tuples as injective functions from $[n]$ to $X$:

Letting $(X,\prec)$ be the underlying ordered set and letting $t_1=f_a$ where $f_a\in X^{\underline{[n_a]}}$ (*i.e. letting $f_a$ be an injective function from $[n_a]$ to $X$*) and $t_2=f_b\in X^{\underline{[n_b]}}$, we have:

$$t_1*t_2 = g\in (f_a(A)\cup f_b(B))^{[|f_a(A)\cup f_b(B)|]}~\text{satisfying}~\\\forall j,k\in[|f_a(A)\cup f_b(B)|]~\text{one has}~j<k\implies g(j)\prec g(k)$$

---

Both of these seem like a lot of words to use for something that can be described much more simply with english rather than symbols: $t_1*t_2$ is the unique tuple such that each entry of $t_1$ and $t_2$ appear once and they appear in the same order as the underlying set.

Comment: I agree this in English is much more simple however in regards to the symbolic statement, I have a question...   So,  to make sure I'm understanding right, I'll work through an example: Let A be the tuple (interpreted as an injective function)  (2,4) and B be the tuple (5,1,2). Then $(f_a(A)\cup f_b(B))$ which is the union of the image set of $f_a$ and $f_b$ = {2,4,5,1} which has a size of 4. Then ${\underline{[|f_a(A)\cup f_b(B)|]}}$ = {1,2,3,4}.  Then $(f_a(A)\cup f_b(B))^{\underline{[|f_a(A)\cup f_b(B)|]}}$ denotes the set of all injective functions from {1,2,3,4} to {2,4,5,1}.

Comment: Now, g belongs to this set and g also satisfy the specified requirement, correct?  (....and g will be unique as only 1 injective function in the set can satisfy the given requirement, yes?).    ....and so we will be left with (1,2,4,5). So, all good. Was this accurate? Thanks

Comment: @boolean essentially.  You have an unnecessary underline the second time you refer to the images, and depending on who you talk to $[n]$ starts at zero and ends at $ n-1$ instead of starting at one and ending at $ n $.  (In either case, it is the "simplest" n-element set)